# MKMapView annotation drag and drop pin, go to user location on button click

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am creating a MKMapView app where user can drag and drop annotation pin to any specific location. Until now its working. But what i want that when user click on refresh button the annotation pin should go to current user's location.
So on button click what i have to make so that `the pin should move from dragged location to user's location.`

Thanks

Comment: Use GPS location to find current location and get latitude longitude after it move that pin to that lat-lon location

Comment: This may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326690/how-to-find-location-using-mapkit-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

**I just give you basic logic, might be helpful for you.**

When your App. run first time at that time add your current **lat and lon value to specific variabel**. (*then after do continue process for drag and drop of annotation.*)

when you click on refresh button then first write

```
[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
```

For remove your annotation to mapView.

and then after get value of `latitude` and `longitude` from Your **Variable**.
and write code for add annotation base on lat and long variable.

Comment: your solution working. but the problem am getting two pins old one and new user location. am just trying to remove the old pin. as am using custom image for pin. [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations]; working but when i zoom still the dragged pin showing on map. any help here.

Comment: @user1997951- u have different pin color then follo this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049280/remove-mkmapview-annotations-with-a-certain-pincolor or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278659/remove-last-added-annotation-from-mkmapview

Comment: `-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation; 
{
    MKAnnotationView *a = [ [ MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    if ( a == nil )
        a = [ [ MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier: @"currentloc" ];
    a.image = [ UIImage imageNamed:@"1234.png" ];
    a.draggable=YES;
    a.canShowCallout =YES;
    
}`. this method calling every time when i zoom and both dragged pin and current userlocation both showing.

Comment: @user1997951- follo this one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494887/mkmapview-mkuserlocation-annotationview/15495226#15495226

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)moveToCurrentLocation:(id)sender 
{    
 [mymapview setCenterCoordinate:[mymapview.userLocation coordinate] animated:YES];
}
```

IT will move map view to your current location (user's location) and remove the current annotation as iPatel said in previous comment.

Comment: if OP manually set lat and long value then this code is not help more

Comment: ohhk.. then sorry i can't help you more on it. but i am also eagerly waiting to see that how it is posable , and if you find it then please  give me the hint as a comment on it.